# Simple DotNetNuke Database Access Example

Tags: c#, database, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Can someone provide a simple C# example of retrieving data from the database in the code behind of a DNN module?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest downloading and studying the data access examples from two recent DNN module development books:

**[Building Websites with DotNetNuke 5](https://www.packtpub.com/building-websites-with-dotnetnuke-5/book)**

- Coauthor's module development guide: http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/

**[Professional DotNetNuke Module Programming](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-DotNetNuke-Module-Programming.productCd-0470171162.html)**

- Sample project update:  http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/302.aspx